# DynamoDB stream trigger invoke for all records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm trying to set up ElasticSearch import process from DynamoDB table. I have already created AWS Lambda and enabled DynamoDB stream with trigger that invokes my lambda for every added/updated record. Now I want to perform initial seed operation (import all records that are currently in my DynamoDB table to ElasticSearch). How do I do that? Is there any way to make all records in a table be "reprocessed" and added to stream (so they can be processed by my lambda)? Or is it better to write a separate function that will manually read all data from the table and send it to ElasticSearch - so basically have 2 lambdas: one for initial data migration (executed only once and triggered manually by me), and another one for syncing new records (triggered by DynamoDB stream events)?

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how Large your dataset is you won't be able to seed your database in Lambda as there is a max timeout of [300 seconds](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/) (EDIT: This is now 15 minutes, thanks @matchish).

You could spin up an EC2 instance and use the SDK to perform a [DynamoDB scan operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property) and batch write to your Elasticsearch instance.

You could also use [Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/) to perform a Map Reduce Job to [export to S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-howto-using-amazon-elastic-mapreduce-with-dynamodb/) and from there process all your data.

Comment: Now max timeout is 15 min

Answer (score 2):

I would write a script that will touch each records in dynamodb. For each items in your dynamodb, add a new property called migratedAt or whatever you wish. Adding this property will trigger dynamodb stream which in turn will trigger your lambda handler. Based on your question, your lambda handler already handles the update so there is no change there.